# Turning off the transition animation when changing workspaces in Compiz (GNOME2/UNITY)

Tags: workspaces, animations

By default, the transition from one virtual desktop to another one under GNOME2 in Ubuntu 11.04 is visualized with a sliding animation. How can I turn that animation off?

Comment: Haven't got a full answer; you need to install **Compiz settings manager**, the settings will be in the **desktop** category

Comment: @danjjl Thanks - if you make that a real answer, I'll tick it off as correct. Please add that in CCSM, the setting is under Desktop/Desktop Wall/Viewport switching/Wall sliding duration.

Comment: Just in case you are wondering: The package name is compizconfig-settings-manager and you can invoke it from your console by typing ccsm.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To change the animation you will need **CompizConfig settings manager**

To install it:

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

or via Ubuntu Software Center.

Open CompizConfig settings manager.

Under **Desktop** → **Desktop Wall** → **Viewport switching** set **Wall sliding duration** to `0`.

Comment: Can this be applied to Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @RNA Still available in Ubuntu 15.04, so I assume it's also in 14.04

Comment: @RNA I have Ubuntu 14.04 and it applies.

Comment: Works as well in Ubuntu 16.04.1 with Unity 7.4.0.

Comment: does not work with Ubuntu 18

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Since Ubuntu 18.04, ubuntu switched from a compiz based window manager to mutter. This answer will only work with compiz as a window manager

Answer (score 3):

for Ubuntu 18.04 I use this, you just need to install the gnome-shell extension (for either [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en), [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/)) and then

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1328/disable-workspace-switch-animation/

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this for Ubuntu 22.04 jammy, you can turn it off in Settings under `Accessibility -> Enable Animations`:

[image: Enable Animations Setting Under Accessibility Menu]

Answer (score 1):

If it is reasonable to turn off *all* Gnome animations, the following works on Ubuntu 21.10:

Install Gnome Tweaks: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks *(edit: search for and install "Tweaks" in the "Ubuntu Software" app, OR install the "gnome-tweaks" package using the APT command line.)*

General > Animations > (turn off the switch)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 it's a toggle under `Appearance`.

Answer (score 0):

Applications -> Appearance -> Behaviour -> Set Visual Effects to Low

[image]

*On a Side note*: Eventually, I ended up reverting back to animations, because the sudden switch from `my dark code screen` to something to `light backgrounds` like browsers was too much for my eyes.