# How to prevent animation during Compiz viewport switching?

Tags: compiz, animations

I want to turn off animation of windows appearing and disappearing when switching between Compiz viewports.
I've tried to turn this animation off by the setting-changes listed in a bullet list below.  However, windows still seem to slide or zoom out of the old viewport or into the new viewport whenever I switch viewports, rather than popping instantaneously into place like I want.  Here is the script I used to test the behavior:

```
#!/bin/sh
S=1.5; W=1680; H=1050

for y in 2 1 0; do
    for x in 2 1 0; do
    wmctrl -o $(($x*$W)),$(($y*$H))
    sleep $S
  done
done
```

Note, I installed `wmctrl` via `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.  The command line
`wmctrl -m; echo $DESKTOP_SESSION; echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP; cat /etc/issue.net; cat /proc/version;uname -a`
on my  i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz system displays the following.

```
Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
ubuntu
Unity
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Linux version 3.2.0-36-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 21:44:52 UTC 2013
Linux biti 3.2.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 21:44:52 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here are the setting changes made in my attempts to fix the problem.  (Note, several of these settings probably are irrelevant, but I haven't found a discussion that explains which, if any, are relevant to the current problem.) (Note, CCSM stands for Compiz config-settings-manager, which I installed with
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`)

• On CCSM/Effects, unchecked the Fading Windows and Animations boxes.
• On CCSM/Desktop/Desktop Wall, set target preview visibility time to zero.
• Also unchecked Show viewport switcher preview and Show live viewport previews.
• In CCSM with expo in search box, clicked expo, and
on Behaviour tab set zoom time to 0.1 (it won't go to less) and checked Immediate moves.
• Set Expo animation to Zoom (there is no animation-off option on the tab)

Summary of question:  How do I turn off animation of windows appearing and disappearing when switching between Compiz viewports, and make those windows just appear as quickly as possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off the transition animation when changing workspaces in Compiz (GNOME2/UNITY)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58553/turning-off-the-transition-animation-when-changing-workspaces-in-compiz-gnome2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A previous question, [Turning off the transition animation when changing workspaces in GNOME2](https://askubuntu.com/q/58553), has [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58585/38324) that partly solves the problem.

First, install `ccsm` (the CompizConfig settings manager) if it isn't present, either via Ubuntu Software Center or with `apt-get`:
 `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
Next, run `ccsm`, and click **Desktop**, **Desktop Wall**, and **Viewport switching** in turn.  Set **Wall sliding duration** to **0**.  (On my Ubuntu 13.04/Unity/Compiz system, that duration defaulted to 300 ms.)

This still leaves the following problem that occurs when I run the test script shown in the question.  When `wmctrl` issues a command to switch to a different viewport, that viewport is immediately displayed (as desired) but also a scaled-down viewport-indicator box animation appears.  In a fraction of a second that box shrinks and disappears.

To deal with that issue, in `ccsm` click **Desktop**, **Desktop Wall**,  and **Viewport switch preview** in turn.  Change **Switch target preview visibility time** from 0.2 to 0.  After that the test script runs cleanly.